# Source that elbow it the border for tznius

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tznius-modesty

Similar [Tznius In Regards to Covering Elbows](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6568/)

Is it true that the elbow is the border of what needs to be covered on the arms for tznius

if yes what is the source of it (I understand it has something to do with women knitting in the marketplace but I do not understand the elbow border)

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate of the question you linked to?

Comment: @DannySchoemann the other asked specifically for lenient sources (that the elbow need not be covered) whereas this is seeking specific sources (that the elbow need be covered but that nothing further need be). Both could (and perhaps should) be better asked as "how much of the arm needs to be covered" and both could be closed as duplicates of such a question. But I don't see that they're duplicates of *one another*.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55155/what-is-the-source-that-forbids-indecent-dress-by-women

Comment: I believe the Mishna Berura (somewhere in OC 75) endorses the elbow border.

Comment: @Bach https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.65a.9/ might be used as a source permiting and prohibiting

Comment: @Bach from here https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.83.1 and  halacha 15 here http://www.chabad.org/1088911/ , it seems the Upper arm is a reveled part of the body