# Is "elbows and knees must be covered" Halacha or widespread Minhag?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tznius-modesty

Is there any credence to the view that those who do not cover knees and elbows are violating Halacha, as opposed to relying on a more lenient opinion of "shok" and "zeroah"? [This thread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/what-are-universal-minimum-standards-of-tznius-for-halachic-purposes/16372#16372) - quotes knees and elbows as a bare minimum, without relevant sources, and a [similar thread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69528/24143) seems to suggest that it is widely debated and more "Dat Yehudit" (minhag) vs "Dat Moshe" (halacha).

Is it **halachically** wrong for women to wear skirts slightly above or at the knee? Or is it a matter of Minhag?

Comment: There's a lot going on here. What is one direct question you want answered that isn't asked in those other places?

Comment: @DoubleAA The other threads seem to indicate that it is a matter of Minhag, and not Halacha. I'm asking if the standard 'knees and elbows uncovered is against halacha' response has any basis, or it is just people being machmir and expecting others to do the same.

Comment: @DoubleAA Edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: This is definitely better, but it's still hard to know what you mean by the words "halacha" and "minhag". And of course we have to allow for the ever present possibility of machloket.  Does an answer with a solitary opinion that wearing said clothing is forbidden by halacha satisfactorily answer your question, even if other opinions exist? What if an opinion holds that the prohibition is fully in force by dint of minhag?

Comment: "violating Halacha, as opposed to relying on a more lenient opinion" are those mutually exclusive? I can think somebody is violating halacha even as they rely on other opinions from me.

Comment: @DoubleAA You raise good points. I was thinking that the area of difference would be whether one has to correct/rebuke someone else for wearing said clothing, by requirement to inform others who are doing Aveiros. As that would get into a more complicated discussion, what if we instead focus on whether there has been a "majority" opinion in the past, of which fringe opinions are not usually held, vs a wide range of opinions that would preclude a "majority" opinion among poskim altogether?

Comment: @DoubleAA Alternatively, a "reliable" posek (a Rav that the chareidi world holds in high esteem, such as the C"C writing MB) that permits a skirt/shirt that is just above the knees/elbows would answer the question for me.

Comment: That's becoming quite a handful again, but whatever it is you want, try to be as clear as you can in the post itself to make sure you get what you want and that people don't post things you don't.

Comment: Is this a question about the exact boundary of how much of the limbs must be covered, or a question about rebuking a woman who is definitely not properly covered?

Comment: @Mordechai The latter, but it is relevant to both, since we are commanded to inform people who are violating commandments, and the exact boundary of how much must be covered helps dictate that.

Answer (score 1):

Dinonline speaks about knees [here](https://dinonline.org/2012/01/19/covering-legs-beneath-the-knee/)

> The principle halachah is that the thigh must be covered, up to and
> including the knee. This is the ruling given by the Mishnah Berurah
> (75:2), and many follow his ruling. In a practical sense, the skirt
> must several centimeters lower than the knee, to ensure that it is
> covered at all times.
>
> However, many authorities (including the Chazon Ish 16:8) write that
> the “shok” of the Gemara is not the thigh, but the leg beneath the
> knee, reaching down to the ankle.
>
> According to these opinions, the entire leg, down to the ankle, should
> be covered. However, there is no obligation to cover the entire leg
> with a skirt or dress, and for the area beneath the kneeit is
> sufficient to wear tights.

and see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6570/13811) for Rav Henkin discussing elbows, as well as [this](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Modesty#cite_ref-6) article which quotes Rav Ovadiah Yosef.

Comment: Can anyone source to Rishonim that it matters lehalacha what the gemara's term shok meant? I can't. This debate is purely academic/lishmah, not lemaaseh.

Comment: @NJM Where does [MB 75:2](https://torah.org/learning/mishna-berura-s75/) mention the knee, or clothing outside of reciting the Shema? It seems like he only mentioned the ankle (which would be a more strict opinion - is this a translator's assumption?), and when a person (male) is reciting Shema her presence.

Comment: @Elie that's indeed a poor translation (though the summary in this answer is also poor, since the Mishna berura never says "and including"; I'd downvote since this answer is literally false, but the OP is just quoting and it's not his fault)